# TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

Good Day,

I am using thymeleaf in springboot using kotlin. I have an object that contains premises in an array.

I am having problem with inlining iteration. my code is as below:

`[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]`

However, the code below works:

`<span th:each=“function : ${geApp.premises}“> [[${function.streetName}]]</span>`
But what i am trying to do is remove the span and use the inline method instead.

The error i received is as per title, in addition the next line is
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)

ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - correlation.id=bd4734ca-92e9-4530-b109-769ca73a2f06 [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]": An error happened during template parsing (template: "[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.email.CovidGeneralExemptionTemplateEmailGenerator.generateHtmlString(CovidGeneralExemptionTemplateEmailGenerator.kt:45)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.email.CovidGeneralExemptionTemplateEmailGenerator.generateEmail(CovidGeneralExemptionTemplateEmailGenerator.kt:27)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.email.EmailService.sendCovidGeneralExemptionAgencyResponse(EmailService.kt:190)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.covid.CovidGeneralExemptionService.triggerEmailService(CovidGeneralExemptionService.kt:541)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.covid.CovidGeneralExemptionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92364e81.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.service.covid.CovidGeneralExemptionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$****7887.triggerEmailService()
at sg.gov.tech.molbbackend.api.resources.covid.CovidGeneralExemptionResourceController.updateGeneralExemptionApplication(CovidGeneralExemptionResourceController.kt:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at sg.gov.tech.logging.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilterLogging(RequestLoggingFilter.kt:54)
at sg.gov.tech.logging.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggingFilter.kt:41)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "function.streetName" (template: "[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]" - line 1, col 52)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
... 115 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "function.streetName" (template: "[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]" - line 1, col 52)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.performInlining(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:440)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleText(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:146)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleText(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:80)
at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleText(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:208)
at org.attoparser.AbstractChainedMarkupHandler.handleText(AbstractChainedMarkupHandler.java:203)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:370)
... 117 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'streetName' cannot be found on null
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
... 134 common frames omitted

Comment: This is reference to:
[# th:each="prod : ${products}"]
   - [(${prod.name})]. Price: [(${prod.price})] EUR/kg
[/] from the docs

Comment: Can you provide the entire stack trace? There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your expression (and the line you pasted doesn't contain the actual error).

Comment: Hey I added the error message at the bottom of the post.

Comment: So the error is: `Property or field 'streetName' cannot be found on null`.  Does `application.premises` contain any null values?

Comment: It does not because when i used this syntax `<span th:each=“function : ${geApp.premises}“> [[${function.streetName}]]</span> ` it works perfectly giving me the output of `<span> Emmerich Ville</span><span> Joseph Land</span>`

Comment: Could you advise me on this? I looked through your post on thymeleaf and saw you had gave an answer `<th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}"></th:block>`. While this works, i tried to use block brackets instead, trying to move towards inlining style in the form of `[#th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}"] Hello [/th:block]`. However that did not work. Can you provide the syntax for the equivalent of the one above? thanks

Comment: The output of it literally just prints out the string itself i.e. [#th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 5)}"] Hello [/th:block] without any loops

Answer (score 0):

In order to use expressions like:

```
[# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]
```

you have to be in text template mode.  Something like this for example:

```
<div th:inline="text">
    [# th:each="function : ${application.premises}"] [[${function.streetName}]] [/]
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. It works but when i try to add a `<br/>` it fails. IS there any way i can add a new line to what i am printing?
I tried: `<div th:inline="text">[#th:block th:each="i: ${application.premises}"] <br/> [[${i.streetName}]]  [/th:block]</div>`

Comment: any advise? Really need help with this